# display list of images on the browser using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to display on the browser 3 images stored in mysql database , but i figured out that just the first image of the first iteration on `loop WHILE` is displayed. how to display the 3 images in the browser ?

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
//$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image,image_type FROM images where id between 2 and 6";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
  
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
$ss=$result['image_type'];

while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
if ($ss == 'php') {
            echo ( $result['image']);
} else if ($ss == 'android') {
            echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );      
}
}
}else{
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

**this code :**

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
//$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image,image_type FROM images where id between 1 and 3";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
  
//$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$result=var_dump(mysqli_fetch_all($r));
//header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
{
 var_dump($row) ;
 }

/*while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
 $ss=$row['image_type'];
if ($ss == 'php') {
            echo ( $row['image']);
} else if ($ss == 'android') {
            echo base64_decode( $row['image'] );      
}
 }*/
}
else{
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

**and this is the result :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

edit. as i've looked throught the problem, you should be able to do:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,
 <?php echo base64_encode( $image_data ); ?>
" />
```

to display all of your image, so below should work:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                $ss = $row['image_type'];
                if ($ss == 'php') {
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo ( $row['image']); ?>" />
                } else if ($ss == 'android') {
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo base64_decode( $row['image'] ); ?> " />     
                }
            }
```

When you are doing **$r->fetch_assoc()** ( so as long as your query is getting you result, your While loop will go on), you are fetching one result row of your data into associative array, so you have your data in **$row** variable.
You have to use that variable for checking your **['image_type']** and getting your **['image']**.

In your code your **$result['image_type']** and **$result['image']** was bound to the first record that you have fetched with **$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r)** ( as documentation states: mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both ).

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $sql = "SELECT image,image_type FROM images where id BETWEEN 2 and 6";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
        $ss = $row['image_type'];
        if ($ss == 'php') {
                    echo ( $row['image']);
        } else if ($ss == 'android') {
                    echo base64_decode( $row['image'] );      
        }
    }
}else{
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

also when you are using **procedular** style, use it all the way, as (examples from php.net):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

or just use **object oriented** style:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

More info, examples here: [**mysqli_result::fetch_assoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: i change it and now , it is showing just the last image

Comment: if i remove $result=mysqli_fetch_array($r) it shows just the first image, when i add it it shows just the last image

Comment: can you do var_dump($r->mysqli_fetch_all()), and check if your images are selected correctly, also check if your $row['image_types'], are for sure 'php' and 'android'.

Comment: i don't understand, where i have to add this var_dump ?

Comment: in your code example, instead of $result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);

Comment: gived me error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_all()

Comment: sry, i mixed up precedural and oo, use var_dump(mysqli_fetch_all($r));

Comment: if the loop has showed the last image , it means the the images are correctly selected from the mysql database, because it passed the first and second and finally it shows the last one,

Comment: then just do while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ var_dump($row) }; to check if your loop will throw out all results

Comment: As you see your while loop is getting all 3 results and throwing them out, btw you shoudln`t store images directly in db instead store your images locations, also add 'header("Content-type: image/jpeg");', if you copy/pasted my code, cuz i've omited it.

Comment: they are stored using Blob Type column, so in this case i cannot show more than one image ?!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107197/discussion-between-fsn-and-otmaane-fikri).